# Is there a way to React to a Certain Message in discord.js Using Message IDs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm aware of `message.react();`, but I can't seem to find anything that specifically reacts to a message using message IDs. My code now reads as

```js
    if(message.content.startsWith('$react')) {
        let splicedMessage = message.content.slice(7);
        let messageParts = splicedMessage.split(' ');
        let pendingMessage = messageParts[0];
        let pendingReaction = messageParts[1];
    }
```

e.g. "$react (messageID) (reaction)". Is there any way that I can react to messageID (`pendingMessage` in the code) with the specified reaction?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [fetch the message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextBasedChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage), and then react to it. I'm assuming that the message is in the channel that you're invoking the command in:

```
message.channel.fetchMessage(pendingMessage)
    .then(msg => msg.react(pendingReaction));
```